# trying to authenticate user registration in mysql with nodejs express, when i try to register a user i get an error of res not defined,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react'
axios from "axios"

  const Register = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  })

  const [err, setError] = useState(null)

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleChange = e => {
  setInputs(prev=>({...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
  }

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
  
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/API/auth/register", inputs)
      // navigate("/login")
      console.log(res)
        }catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
      setError(err. Response)
     }
   }

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form className="registerForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" required name="username" onChange= 
     {handleChange}/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" required name="email" onChange= 
     {handleChange}/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" required name="password" onChange= 
     {handleChange}/>
      button onClick=handleSubmit className="registerBtn"> Register</button>
        {err && <p>{err}</p>}
        <span>Already have an account? <Link to="/login"> Login</Link></span>
      </form>
    </div>
   )
  }

  export default Register
```

i want to log to console the user has been created message when i click on register,
then the new user details should be saved to the MySQL table with users.
please help.

have tried defining res and changing the err. Response to err.res, still it didn't work

Comment: You need to capture the response of your API request in a variable. Try this: `const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/API/auth/register", inputs)`

Comment: as mentioned by @PrerakSola, you need to store response of the api first.

Comment: thanks for your response, i am getting response 200 but I am not seeing "user created" in the data object

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that bothered me, though they might be formatting or pasting errata:

1. `axios from "axios"` => `import axios from "axios"`

`import` is missing, unless `import`-less syntax is allowed nowadays.

2. `await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/API/auth/register", inputs)`  => `const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/API/auth/register", inputs)`

You have to assign the async resolution (success result) to something, because what's the point if you don't use the response? (plus you're referencing `res` on the next line, so you need it) unless all you want to know is whether it went through alright because if it doesn't the promise rejects.

3. `setError(err. Response)` => `setError(err)`

Does `err` have this `Response` attribute? if so, remove the space and make it `err.Response`

4. `button onClick=handleSubmit className="registerBtn">` => `<button onClick={handleSubmit} className="registerBtn">`

Aside from the button tag needing left caret, I believe `handleSubmit` has to be enclosed with curly braces. I forgot what they're doing internally, but without them, react won't properly trigger the function on event in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your response but all the errors you pointed out are correctly done in the main code, it's just the stack overflow editor that maybe removed them